# How do I get the Angler?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I can't get Angler NPC in Terraria on iOS. I think this is because I made my whole world flat and put lizhared bricks on top for armour. When the Angler was finally released on iOS I made a beach of my own and hoped the Angler NPC would come but unfortunately he didn't.

[image]

Comment: I'm fairly certain you will need to generate a new world to get the new stuff

Comment: What @Aequitas said, but also because the Angler will only spawn in the ocean biome, and if the mobile version is like the desktop version that background indicates that you're not in the ocean biome, for whatever reason

Answer (score 1):

According to the terraria gamepedia, the Angler will spawn at random and he is not guaranteed to spawn on either ocean immediately. You may have to simply wait for him to spawn.

Also, since he is a Town NPC a suitable 'house' is required in order for the Angler to appear. If you do not have an empty house built, the Angler will not appear. Ever.

A proper ocean biome must also be present for the Angler to arrive. If you don't have an ocean or have obstructed yours you can build an artificial ocean out of sand and water. If the 'Ocean' music is playing and the background is a vast sea of water with a green hill or two than the Ocean biome is present. If not, than you may have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the Angler wasn't spawning on my old world too. So when I started up a new one and went straight to the beach to either the left or right I found him, laying there sleeping on the beach. So my hypothesis was you can only get him when you create a new world. Try it out and see what happens. After all, Terraria can get boring if you have nothing to do